# How do I use a for statement to populate an array with NSNumbers in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have the following code that I thought would be clever enough to populate an NSMutableArray with NSNumbers by using a for statement. What I want to achieve is passing a method a number like 32 and then having it pass me back an array of numbers from 1 to 32 that I can display in my picker. Here is what I have:

```
+(NSMutableArray *) getFeetDownArray:(NSInteger)i{

NSMutableArray *feetDownArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:nil];



for (NSInteger Int=1;Int<=i;Int++) 
{
    NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber alloc];
    [myNumber initWithInt:Int];
    [feetDownArray addObject:myNumber];
    [myNumber release];



}

return feetDownArray;
```

}

Now, when I call [MyClass getFeetDownArray:32] and assign it to an array, I would expect to receive [myArray count] to return 33 as the count, but I am getting nothing. Can anyone see what I am doing incorrectly here? I have also tried removing the nil at the end of the initWithObjects when I declare the *feetDownArray, but it still doesn't work. I am getting no errors in xcode either, just nothing returns for the count of that array and I have no items to display in my picker.

Comment: Don't split apart your `+alloc` and `-init` messages. That won't solve the problem you're seeing, but just don't do it anyway. :)

Comment: One other thing, `return [feetDownArray autorelease]`. Then retain it in the caller if you want to keep it longer than local scope. It's possible your code is correct depending how you call getFeetDownArray, but the convention is that most functions don't pass ownership of the return value to the caller.

Comment: yes and don't name your variables with keywords like "Int", choose another name for your local variable. And moreover, don't name your variables with Titlecase, use camelCase (with the first letter being lowercase) instead. See Cocoa naming conventions

Comment: Good suggestions, Jonathan and morningstar. I have implemented those, although as you say, it does not solve the underlying problem. AliSoftware, it was an oversight to not use camelCase. I do use proper naming conventions most times, but have been rewriting this code so much, that I let that one slip by. Thanks for the reminder though, it does make it much easier to read.

Comment: Okay, so my issue was in assigning my NSMutable array returned from the method to another array and then using that array to populate the picker. Must be doing something wrong there. The code I originally submitted should work fine when I skip the middle man and just grab the array count from the method in my picker method. I tried to post this as an answer, but since I'm new, I still have 7 hours to go before I can answer my own question. :) Thanks everyone for the excellent suggestions. What a great community!!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what happens when you call "initWithObjects:nil", that might be a problem.  I would do it this way:

```
+(NSMutableArray *) getFeetDownArray:(NSInteger)size
{  
    NSMutableArray *feetDownArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:size];

    for (int j=1; j<=size; j++)  {     
        NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:j];
        [feetDownArray addObject:myNumber];   
    }  
    return [feetDownArray autorelease]; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet. It is a new way to do what I am trying to achieve but I ended up with the same result as before with no errors. I am going to post my code that I use in the viewDidLoad and picker methods because perhaps I am making a mistake there and not in the above? Could be both, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to autorelease your array.  You can also just pass in an integer and have the method do all the NSNumber translation to further encapsulate your code:

```
+ (NSMutableArray *) getFeetDownArray: (int) arraySize
{
    NSMutableArray *feetDownArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int currentNumber = 1; currentNumber <= arraySize; currentNumber++)
    {
        NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt: currentNumber];
        [feetDownArray addObject: number];
    }

    return [feetDownArray autorelease];
}
```

Comment: You may want to check this code because although the other suggestions were not giving me what I was looking for, they did not produce errors like this one did. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: Well I had a retain in there that was not needed, I didn't have Xcode in front of me to try it out and missed that.  However, even with the retain, the code compiled and ran fine.  It added an array with all the numbers needed inside based on the parameter being passed into the class method.  What version of Xcode are you using, as the code stood and even with the update, no errors are given.

Comment: Hi Hans, I am using Xcode 4.0.2 Build 4A2002a. Unfortunately, I had made a mistake elsewhere and have discovered my original code was just fine with a few best coding practice pieces missing that I have now added. I'm sure this code is fine too, but it did crash on me when I tried to run it originally without any discernible error messages unfortunately to provide here. Thanks again for the help.